# Change controls zero point in canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas

When i draw items in canvas, the position is take from top of the item inside canvas:

```
<Canvas Name="cnvMain"
        Width="80"
        Height="80">
  <Ellipse Canvas.Top="20"
           Canvas.Left="40"
           Width="40"
           Height="40"
           Fill="Gray" />
</Canvas>
```

[image]

Now what i would need is to take the measurement from the bottom of the element, like this:

[image]

**In the end i would like to be able to set the distance from the bottom of the Ellipse to the top of the Canvas.
NB: Ellipse can sometimes not be a circle and flipping it upside down is not an option. Also i dont know the height before runtime so setting negative margin in xaml will not work also.**

(Picture and example xaml taken from: http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/centering-text-within-a-wpf-shape-using-a-canvas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify the distance of the bottom of the Ellipse to the bottom of the Canvas, you could replace `Canvas.Top` by `Canvas.Bottom`:

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Bottom="20" Canvas.Left="40" Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Gray"/>
```

For the distance from the bottom of the Ellipse to the top of the Canvas, you may specify a negative Margin:

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="40" Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Gray"
         Margin="0,-40,0,0"/>
```

or an appropriate RenderTransform:

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="40" Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Gray">
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

In order to invert the y direction of the whole Canvas coordinate system, you may apply a RenderTransform to the Canvas:

```
<Canvas ... RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    ...
</Canvas>
```

Edit: You may also put the Ellipse in another Canvas with zero Height, and attach it to the lower Canvas border:

```
<Canvas Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="40" Width="0" Height="0">
    <Ellipse Canvas.Bottom="0" Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Gray"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I like the RenderTransform solution because i dont always know the height of the ellipse so i cant set the margin in xaml. Only problem now with RenderTransform is that it flips the whole ellipse upside down. Any ideas how to do it wihout fliping?